# Elasticsearch stuck in yellow status

Tags: elasticsearch

I fired the following command on elasticsearch

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "threadpool.index.queue_size": -1
    }
}
```

But now my elastuicsearch cluster health is stuck in yellow. Nothing is moving, and the cat recovery api gives following

```
books 0     613   replica done  server1.internal.com server2.internal.com n/a        n/a      1     100.0%        79        100.0%        
books 0     53479 replica done  server2.internal.com server3.internal.com n/a        n/a      146   100.0%        435062890 100.0%        
books 1     592   replica done  server1.internal.com server2.internal.com n/a        n/a      1     100.0%        79        100.0%        
books 1     5901  replica done  server2.internal.com server3.internal.com n/a        n/a      198   34.3%         449403096 2.7%          
books 2     551   replica done  server1.internal.com server2.internal.com n/a        n/a      1     100.0%        79        100.0%        
books 2     9018  replica done  server2.internal.com server3.internal.com n/a        n/a      201   28.9%         451881473 4.4%          
books 3     519   replica done  server1.internal.com server2.internal.com n/a        n/a      1     100.0%        79        100.0%        
books 3     3869  replica done  server2.internal.com server3.internal.com n/a        n/a      170   61.8%         434156880 1.2%          
books 4     525   replica done  server1.internal.com server2.internal.com n/a        n/a      1     100.0%        79        100.0%        
books 4     33468 replica done  server2.internal.com server3.internal.com n/a        n/a      136   100.0%        428616146 100.0%
```

For about 30 minutes there has been no progress.

Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: Making threadpool size as unbounded is a bad idea. How many machines are you using ?

Comment: You can use _cat/shards to see which shards are unallocated.  It should also give you an idea of which node is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out this was due to corrupted disk on one of the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Classification of Elasticsearch Cluster Status:

**RED:** Some or all of (primary) shards are not ready.

**YELLOW:** Elasticsearch has allocated all of the primary shards, but some/all of the replicas have not been allocated.

**GREEN:** Cluster is fully operational. Elasticsearch is able to allocate all shards and replicas to machines within the cluster.